# Get post ID in post/page edit area

Tags: posts, admin

How can i get "post id" in post edit area for add_filter in functions.php?

I want to change file name automatically during upload. so i need to obtain post id.

the code is as follows:

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_name' );   
function custom_upload_name($file)
{       
  list($name, $ext) = explode('.', $file['name']);
  $file['name'] = $post_ID.'.'.$ext;    
return $file;
}
```

Edited:

the final and working code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_name' );   
function custom_upload_name($file)
{       
  $post_ID = $_POST['post_id'];   
  list($name, $ext) = explode('.', $file['name']);
  $file['name'] = $post_ID.'.'.$ext;    
return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using $_POST['post_id'] in the upload area as file.php does not include the global $post object.

Comment: $post_ID = $_GET['post_id'] dose not work.

Comment: @kami Updated my answer. Use $_POST instead.

Comment: I use `$_GET['post']` and it does work. Take a look at the post editor screen url to determine which one is correct. Mine is like this: `http://mysite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=5&action=edit&message=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using global $post object?

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_name' );   

function custom_upload_name($file){ 
  global $post;      
  list($name, $ext) = explode('.', $file['name']);
  $file['name'] = $post->ID.'.'.$ext;    
return $file;
}
```